# I have an animation I want to have executed once it is showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

As the title says, the problem is that whenever the user begins scrolling, it animates. How can I fix it such that once the element is showing, the animation begins? Please note that the section where the animation is supposed to start is not the first thing you see once the page loads; it's down the page.

Comment: The title say nothing. Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: You should share more details like whether you are using a library for animating stuff. If yes, which one, and what are the parameters used for animating the elements